# Youtube data api v3 - subscription call failing

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've developed a php app in codeignter to view, search and play videos - all via the youtube api. Works just fine.

Trying to add a function that will retrieve all the subscriptions I have in my youtube account but can't get it to work. Keep getting the following message:

Message: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&key=[myapikey]): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Any clues as to why this is happening on this call and not on the others?

Comment: If you use the parameter `mine`. Maybe you need the OAuth access token.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you explain a little more about the oauth token? Or is there a way to use the command without using 'mine:?

Comment: OK, I have wrote a doc [Authorization](https://python-youtube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html)。 You  can see this. But that library not support subscription now.:).  Also you can follow the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) to use the Try This Api.